# Java Files.write NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to write some text to a file using `Files.write()` method.

```
byte[] contents = project.getCode().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

try {
    Files.write(project.getFilePath(), contents, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

According to the API, if the file doesn't exist, it will be created and then written to.

However, I get this:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\Default.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does directory `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work` exist? (and why do you develop as an admin?)

Comment: use file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

Comment: Yes, I'm stupid. I forgot to check if the folder exists :D

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should be able to create a file, but you can't create a directory.  You may need to check the directory `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work` exists first.

You can do

```
Path parentDir = project.getFilePath().getParent();
if (!Files.exists(parentDir))
    Files.createDirectories(parentDir);
```

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka if you don't, you can get a `FileAlreadyExistsException`

Comment: If `getParent()` is used, `FileAlreadyExistsException` will never be thrown. Parent is always a directory. From the documentation: "FileAlreadyExistsException - if dir exists but is not a directory"

Comment: flawless answer Peter!

Answer (score 1):

The file will be written if default OpenOptions parameter is used. If you specify CREATE, default parameters will not be used, but it is used just CREATE. Try to add WRITE in addition to CREATE, or just leave that parameter empty

Comment: wrong. `Files.write` will add `WRITE` regardless of any options given. see `java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream` source